# readExternal() not working as expected?

Tags: java, serialization, externalizable

I am using `Externalization` in this example. First I serialized the object into the file named "tmp" using `writeExternal()` method .But when I am deserializing it using `readExternal()` i am getting the output as follows...

```
default
The original car is name=Maruti
year2009
age10
The new Car is name=null
year0
age10
```

Here why the name and the year of the car is not serialized? And if is serialized, why i am getting `null` and `0` as their values...Please specify..

```
import java.io.*;

class Car implements Externalizable
{

    String name;
    int year;

    static int age;
    public Car()
    {
        super();
        System.out.println("default");
    }

    Car(String n,int y)
    {
        name=n;
        year=y;
        age=10;
    }

    public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException
    {
        out.writeObject(name);
        out.writeInt(year);
        out.writeInt(age);
    }

    public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        while(in.available()>0){
            name=(String)in.readObject();
            year=in.readInt();
            age=in.readInt();
        }
    }

    public String toString() 
    {
        return("name="+name+"\n"+"year"+year+"\n" +"age" +age);
    }
}

public class ExternExample
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Car car=new Car("Maruti",2009);
        Car newCar=null;
        try{
           FileOutputStream fout=new FileOutputStream("tmp");
           ObjectOutputStream so=new ObjectOutputStream(fout);
           so.writeObject(car);
           so.flush();
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        try
        {
            FileInputStream fis=new FileInputStream("tmp");
            ObjectInputStream oin=new ObjectInputStream(fis);
            newCar = (Car) oin.readObject();
        }
        catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);}
        System.out.println("The original car is "+car);
        System.out.println("The new Car is "+newCar);
    }
}**
```

Answer (score 3):

Get rid of the loop and the `available()` test. You've only written one object, so you should only read one object, so there is no reason to loop, let alone call `available()`. There are few correct uses of that method, and this isn't one of them.

If you extended `Serializable` instead of `Externalizable` and simply removed the `read/writeExternal()` methods it would work just as well.

Your main method isn't closing the `ObjectOutputStream` or `ObjectInputStream.`